# Creating conditional statements in the same PHP function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, gravityforms

I'm currently trying to solve a problem on my wordpress site using Gravity Forms. I'm trying to populate the a dropdown field on 3 different forms with a list of users dependent on the their "service" which is specified in their metadata. For example: Form 1 shows a dropdown of all users with "Service 1" specified in their metadata, Form 2 shows a dropdown of all users with "Service 2" in their metadata.

I've found some code online which I've put into my Functions.php file which works as I want it to, but only for 1 form at a time. I've tried changing the relevent IDs/meta_values and each time I save it, the correct form updates and the others get wiped.

If I copy and paste the code to have multiple instances, I get an error as PHP doesn't allow for the same function to be called multiple times.

My PHP knowledge is reasonably limited and I've tried to chop it up to add multiple "if" statements based on different IDs and $metas but so far to no avail. Is anyone able to look at the code and see an obvious solution?

---

This is the code that currently works for 1 form at a time.

---

```
add_filter("gform_pre_render", "populate_userdrop");

add_filter("gform_admin_pre_render", "populate_userdrop");

function populate_userdrop($form){

    if($form["id"] != 1)

    return $form;

    $items = array();
    $metas = get_users(array(
    'meta_value'     => 'Service 1',
));

if (is_array($metas))
{

foreach($metas as $meta)  $items[] = array("value" => $meta->display_name, "text" => $meta->display_name);
}
foreach($form["fields"] as &$field)
    if($field["id"] == 1){
    $field["choices"] = $items;
}

return $form;
}
```

---

I have tried to cut it up like this but so far I can't get it working

---

```
add_filter("gform_pre_render", "populate_userdrop");

add_filter("gform_admin_pre_render", "populate_userdrop");

function populate_userdrop($form){

    $metas = get_users(array(
    'meta_value'     => 'Service 1',
    ));

    $metas2 = get_users(array(
    'meta_value'     => 'Service 2',
    ));

    if($form["id"] != 1)

    return $form;

    $items = array();

if (is_array($metas))
{
foreach($metas as $meta)  $items[] = array("value" => $meta->display_name, "text" => $meta->display_name);
}

    if($form["id"] != 2)

     return $form;

    $items = array();

if (is_array($metas2))
{

foreach($metas2 as $meta)  $items[] = array("value" => $meta->display_name, "text" => $meta->display_name);
}   

foreach($form["fields"] as &$field)
    if($field["id"] == 1){
    $field["choices"] = $items;
    }   

return $form;
}
```

Comment: `switch case ` -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Some sensible indentation would also make the code so much easier to read (and troubleshoot)

Comment: Firstly it's not WordPress that won't allow you to have multiple functions with the same name in the same scope, it's PHP. Secondly, your code isn't working because of what you are telling it to do. You are telling it, that if `form["id"] != 1; return $form` and then further down saying if `form["id"] != 2; return $form` so on creating the forms, the first form stops at the second one and the second form stops at the first one. You should be able to achieve this with `meta_query`